# Ask user for folder (open browse dialog)

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Is it possible to ask the user for a folder in Acrobat by javascript?. To make the user choose a folder in a dialog window? If possible I would like the dialog box to start from j:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In Acrobat JavaScript, there's no property you can use to set the default directory for a file browser dialog. However, Acrobat tends to remember the path to the last file selected by the dialog so once a user navigates to that folder once, they're likely to end up there the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through **"Action Wizard"**. [Ctrl/Cmd + Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F6Gv.gif) Choose **"create new Action"**, then Choose **"A Folder on My Computer"** from dropdown menu Located under **Start with:** section.

Choose **"Execute Javascript"** from More Tools Panel by default it add into steps section, click on **icon** under Options, type/paste your javascript here then click **OK**. From **save to** section dropdown menu choose option what you prefer.

Click on save and enter action name click on save again.

hope this will help you.

---

using Acrobat X.